# Why is that ! Low accuracy with special sigmoid activation function

Tags: python, function, keras, activation

I'm doing a study on activation functions. However, I get a constant (low) success rate in the activation functions I wrote. For example, I get a constant success rate, especially in exp () expressions.
Sample work codes are as follows; However, when I define sigmoid function as sigmoid (x), I can get a high success rate. I didn't know what to do. I'd appreciate it if you could help me out at this point. Good work.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def Sech(x): #Sigmoid 
   return 1.0 / (1.0 + tf.exp(-x))

get_custom_objects().update({'Sech': Activation(Sech)})
model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=24))
model.add(Activation(Sech))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
```

Comment: I once used `layers.Lambda(lambda x: Sech(x))(x)` and it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But let me remove the Activation and write Lamda like that.